# How to perform maven release from local machine

Tags: release-management, maven-release-plugin

Sometimes we need to perform maven release from our local development environment for some easy artifacts. 
Here is the way how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have all the setup (adding plugin, defining SCM etc) done for maven project to create a release.

This command helps creating release.
mvn -B -f /proj_path/pom.xml -DdevelopmentVersion={Snapshot version} -DreleaseVersion={Release version} -Dresume=false release:prepare release:perform

Prerequisite: settings.xml file should have authN detail.